# GoogleMaps API mapOptions doesn't work

Tags: google-maps

unfortunately the part "mapOptions" at my code doesn't work.

Without the part "map.setCenter(new GLatLng(152.134588, 31.647134), 7);" i couldn't see the Map after loading.

My Code:

```
function givedata() {
          if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 0,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(152.134588, 31.647134),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_cus"), mapOptions);
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(152.134588, 31.647134), 7);
    [...]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What library are you using for the G objects (GLatLng etc), perhaps this is conflicting with the maps API (google.maps.whatever) in some way?

Comment: It seems that you are mixing v2 and v3 library code.

Comment: How are you including the API?  GBrowserIsCompatible is from the [deprecated (and turned off) Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference). If you are including v3, you should get an obvious error.  If you are including v2, you should also get an obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an issue with the options object, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/ref_mapoptions.asp) for reference, you have used the object correctly, though perhaps try changing the order of the options within and increasing the zoom level from 0 (all the way out) though I can't see why this would be an issue.